# Osamu Dazai's book titled "Josei Gakkou (Highschool Girl)" in "Tsuki ga Kirei"

Tags: merchandise, tsuki-ga-kirei

In some episodes of *Tsuki ga Kirei*, I noticed that the main MC is borrowing some books called "Josei Gakkou(Highschool Girl) by Osamu Dazai".

I started looking for those books on the internet, and I found [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012HU8L8I) which is kinda related to?

Is this the correct book and is there any translation available for this book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no work called *Josei Gakkou* (Highschool Girl) by Osamu Dazai, but there's **女生徒 (*Joseito*, Schoolgirl)**.

The English version is titled *Schoolgirl*, translated by Allison Markin Powell and published by One Peace Books.

> [image: The book cover of "Schoolgirl"]